# How to get windowspecification object for an application

Tags: pywinauto

I am using pywinauto to manipulate excel. Because I am working with different AddIns, sometimes the title of Excel will differ. You might see

- Book 1 - Super App
- Book 1 - Mega Super App is Online
- Book 1 - Super App 2

I know that I can do this to manipulate the Excel menu of the second item

```
import pywinauto as pywin
app = pywin.Application(backend="uia").connect(path="EXCEL.EXE", title="Book*")
app.Book1MegaSuperAppisOnline.Ribbon.Ribbon.RibbonTabs.MegaSuperApp.click_input()
```

How should I interrogate app to find the correct 'pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification' name which I should be using? I know how to find an application.window, but not how to find an application.windowspecification.

Can't find an example in the docs, and can't work out the API ... help !